# Excel Formulas - VBA takes too long to response(calculate) ,How to speed up?

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Here is below code to for vlookup and countif.

its takes more than 5 min to complete, any idea's to speed up my macro ?

```
With Sheets("HW INVENT")
    lRow = .Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.screenupdating=false
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    .Range("C2:C" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LAST_WEEK_KPI!C[-1]:C,2,0)"
    .Range("D2:D" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C2:R" & lRow & ",RC[-2])"
    .Range("F2:F" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LAST_WEEK_KPI!C[-1]:C,2,0)"
    .Range("G2:G" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C5:R" & lRow & ",RC[-2])"
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.screenupdating=true
End With
```

Any idea why it takes too long to complete ..  Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is `Application.screenupdationg` just a typo here or is it in the actual code? It should be `Application.ScreenUpdating`

Comment: Changes done.. thanks for that .. still its takes the more time to complete .. suggest me if any ..

Comment: For better performance try to restrict ranges. Look like you have maximized them.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment momobo .. Could you please explain me more .. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying formulas, try like this:

```
.Range("C2:C" & lRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupvalue, Range("A:A"), 1, 0)
```

this method `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupvalue, Range("A:A"), 1, 0)`
directly returns the value.

Comment: Thanks Alv ... above method runs faster than my macro .. :)